# Restoring with Akeeba to a new site on cpanel

Tags: database, akeebabackup

I've backed up my Joomla site with Akeeba, and I'm using Akeeba Kickstart to put the site into a dev environment on a different server with its own cpanel.

The dev server has its own database and database prefix, but when I get to the restore database part of Akeeba Kickstart, it's loading the DB name, prefix, user and pass from the live site.

Would I need to change all of this to my current cpanel info?

Answer (score 6):

Yes you will need to enter the details for the development server database at this step.

By default, Akeeba Kickstart will display the database details from the site it was backed up from... it assumes that you're restoring to the same site that you backed up.